# Discontinuity Regression

Tags: spss, regression-discontinuity

I'm writing a political economy Master's thesis regarding the effects of the Euro Crisis on the rise of separatism in Spain (Catalan independence for example).

The idea is to show that the Crisis has acted as an exogenous shock, causing a sudden rise in separatism.

Is a discontinuity regression the correct method to prove this and if so, how does it work, please? The variables I was thinking of using would be time v. separatism, unemployment v. separatism, GDP growth v. separatism, etc.

Can it be done on SPSS?

To note: I'm not very experienced with statistics.

Comment: For structural changes in the data [like Euro crisis in your case], you can introduce dummy/indicator variable.